# The method asList(T...) in the type Arrays is not applicable for the arguments (Role, Role)

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0

I am trying to test the OAuth 2.0 Authorization using Postman if I have implement it right.

I am sending this one by Postman an expecting token in return

http://localhost:8080/oauth/token/grant_type=password&username=user&password=user

But I have error in this part of code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class KamehouseApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(KamehouseApplication.class, args);

    }

    @Autowired
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth, UserRepository repo, User user) throws Exception {
        if (repo.count() == 0)
            user = (new User("user", // username
                    "user", // password
                    Arrays.asList(new Role("USER"), new Role("ACTUATOR"))));// roles

        repo.save(user);

        auth.userDetailsService(s -> new CustomUserDetails(repo.findByUsername(s)));
    }
}
```

The part that is underlined in red is

```
Arrays.asList(new Role("USER"), new Role("ACTUATOR"))));
```

Saying

```
The method asList(T...) in the type Arrays is not applicable for the arguments (Role, Role)
```

This is my User class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public int id;

    public String firstname;
    public String lastname;
    public String username;
    public String password;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Role> roles;

    public User() {
    }

    //Getters/Setters
```

Comment: Are you sure you are importing `java.util.Arrays` and not some other `Arrays` class? What's the signature of the `User` constructor?

Comment: What's the java version?

Comment: @lealceldeiro java version "1.8.0_131"

Comment: @assylias yes I have imported from `java.util.Arrays` and please see my update for constructor.

Comment: Maybe not the issue but I don't see any constructor for `User(String username, String password, List roles)`... only `User()`.

Comment: Do you get the same thing if on another line you do `List<Role> roles = Arrays.asList(new Role("USER"), new Role("ACTUATOR")` for me with "Long" instead of role works just fine? also you don't have a User constructor with parameters. also don't need wrapping parenthesis at `user = (new User(...));` also remove User user from method signature you don't ever use the passed in value.

Comment: @lealceldeiro have added constructor for `User(String username, String password, List roles)` but still same

Comment: @mavriksc have tried before also but it's not working.

Comment: @lealceldeiro check my solution I edited my question. I have just changed my constructor in role class

Comment: @user9347049 Great! You should move that edit from the question to an answer in order to help future readers.

Comment: @mavriksc I found solution I haven't changed anything regarding list it self I just changed constructor in my role.java class. Thanks for all tips :)

Comment: @lealceldeiro Thank you! I just put it as answer. Thanks for all the tips! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

I have changed constructor

```
public Role() {

}
```

to

```
public Role(String string) {

}
```

to my Role.java file and also added

```
public User(String username, String password, List roles) {
}
```

to my User.java and now it's working just fine.